# Un-bind custom domain after account expiry in Jelastic

Tags: java, dns

I'm unable to un-bind the custom domain ( www.udhc.co.in ) I had bound to http://boseapp1.jelastic.servint.net/

From my domain registrar's control panel, I've modified the settings ( CNAME records ) after my jelastic account expired to a different domain. So, www.udhc.co.in shouldn't point to http://boseapp1.jelastic.servint.net/ anymore.

However, www.udhc.co.in still points to the old(expired) app domain.

The dashboard on the Jelastic control panel doesn't even have an option to un-bind after expiry of my trial!

How do I  un-bind the custom domain as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding in Jelastic dashboard is set only for internal resolving purpose. So, when you remove your Jelastic URL from CNAME records, your domain www.udhc.co.in stops pointing to http://boseapp1.jelastic.servint.net/. 
The possible reason of your issue is that CNAME records are cached by your domain registrator for some time. Try to contact their support to figure out.